# Getting total of from two separate mysql database tabel

Tags: mysql, html-table, sum

Currently I am working on two separate tables on Mysql database,  ITEM, CUSTOMER.
Details as under

```
ITEM
Id
Name
Cost
Payment Balance
CustomerName

CUSTOMER
Id
CustomerName
Balance
```

I need to achieve two tasks:

1. when I insert a record to Item Database the balance field on CUSTOMER database should be updated.
2. when I see all Items purchased by a Customer the balance total of that Customer should be calculated.

Please help.

Currently I am using following codes :

```
$Id=$_GET['Id'];
........
$query = "SELECT Item.id, Item.Name, Item.Cost, Item.PaymentBalance,Item FROM Item INNER JOIN customer ON customer.CustomerName = visam.CustomerName where customer.Id='$Id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td width="20px" ><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td width="310px" ><? echo $rows['Name']; ?> </td>
<td width="310px" ><? echo $rows['Cost']; ?> </td>
<td width="210px" ><? echo $rows['PaymentBalance']; ?> </td>
```

Results now showing correctly but I do not know how to get the total of Payment Balance at the end of the page.

Comment: Might is suggest linking the two tbales on the customer id field instead of the customer name. This is common practice, and much faster. Comparing numbers is way more efficient then comparing strings.

Comment: You are right, used to do that, this is just a quick work, I am not very good at coding. I started with ID but later changed to name as I do not know how to populated the customer name in ITEM table , as only ID is stored there.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $total_balance=0; ?>

..// your while loop

<?php $total_balance+=$rows['PaymentBalance']; ?>

..// end while loop

<?php var_dump($total_balance); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend showimg the balance as the last row of your table

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$balance += $rows['PaymentBalance'];
<tr>
<td width="20px" ><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td width="310px" ><? echo $rows['Name']; ?> </td>
<td width="310px" ><? echo $rows['Cost']; ?> </td>
</tr>
}
<tr>
<td width="210px" ><? echo $balance; </tr>?>
```

**EDIT**

Also I think you can get away with not putting the balance in your table **IF** it represents the sum of your "cost"... such that

```
$balance += $rows['Cost'];
```

Comment: Dear voodoo417, Shawn; Thanks for your reply, but the code did not produce any results. This code should search all the ITEMS ordered by the customer and sum the Balance unpayed, maybe I should populated the balance field on CUSTOMER table when I insert Item records.

Comment: See the edit update. Also can you show an example of your table schema so we can see what your data looks like?

Comment: this is my code : http://www.etakartourism.com/code/Customer.txt and this is my data table http://www.etakartourism.com/code/table.jpg

Comment: If i am understanding your table schemas you have the column "balance" in both tables but in your code in your original question you are calling it "PaymentBalance". You can either change your column name to that OR you were trying to alias the balance column in which case it would look like this: SELECT Item.id, Item.Name, Item.Cost, Item.Balance AS 'PaymentBalance',Item FROM Item INNER...
Then your code $balance += $rows['PaymentBalance'] should now work. Also as a final note watch case sensitivity. select balance... $rows['balance'].